# Получение сканированного изображение через python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scanner, принтер

Mожет кто-нибудь реализовывал подключение к принтерам по сети через `python`, для сканирования изображений. использую twain, но он видит только локально добавленные wia, помогите делать сканирование через wsd протокол ОС Windows. поэтому модуль sane не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна чисто автоматизация, то воткните модуль `win32api` и пусть он имитирует нажатия клавиш, которые вам нужны. Не совсем эффективно, зато будет работать ;D